# How add a few files into playlist

Tags: java, android, playlist

I create new playlist using next approach:

```
ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
ContentValues value = new ContentValues();
value.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME, "Name PlayList");
value.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.DATE_MODIFIED, System.currentTimeMillis());
resolver.insert(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, value);
```

I have list (`ArrayList<File>`) of mp3 files.

How can I add this files into newly PlayList?

Comment: see `android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members`

Comment: and here you have some sample code: https://gist.github.com/dzwillpower/5866205#file-musicutils-java-L455, see lines 475-480

Comment: @pskink, could you please explain, what is `int [] ids` in code sample?

Comment: see line 478...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I have only list of File, so at first I need to get audio Id using path to file:

```
public static long getTrackIdByPath(Context context, String pathToFile){
long id = - 1;
String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                       MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA};
String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " like ?";
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        projection, selection,
        new String[] {pathToFile}, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
if(cursor.getCount() > 0)
    id = cursor.getLong(0);
cursor.close();
return id;
```

After that I can add audio to playlist:

```
ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
long trackId = getTrackIdByPath(context, pathToFile);
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri("external", playListId);
    Cursor cursor = resolver.query(uri, new String[] {"count(*)"}, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int last = cursor.getInt(0);
    cursor.close();
    ContentValues value = new ContentValues();
        value.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.PLAY_ORDER, ++last);
        value.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID, trackId);

    resolver.insert(uri, value);
```